# Why there are so many duplicate SQL functions in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In Amazon Redshift, I found that there are many SQL functions with different names but does exactly the same thing. The Redshift document even mentions those as synonym functions.

For eg: [**STRPOS Function**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STRPOS.html) has two other synonym function - CHARINDEX Function and POSITION Function. All three do the exact same thing - Return the position of a substring within a specified string.

What is the reason for having three functions for exact same task? Is there any performance difference among these?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly to make it more compatible with other forms of SQL.

For example, `CHARINDEX` is a command from Microsoft SQL Server, whereas `POSITION` is a command from PostgreSQL (upon which Amazon Redshift is based).

Given that Redshift is from Amazon, I would guess that the answer is "because customers asked for it!"